# How to fetch the android screen image in an android application

Tags: android, python

I want some way to get the android screen image in a python program. For this I want some way, where I connect my computer and android device, then to a port say on my computer port number 13390, I can get the present screen image of the android device. So, this becomes easy solution for my application, I can just make a request to that port number and get the image.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an Android instrumentation test by using the [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#takeScreenshot(java.io.File,%20float,%20int)) to capture the screenshot as a Bitmap or File. Once you have the image, run a local http server on the phone and fetch it via a normal http GET call in the python client.

To get the screenshot Bitmap you would:

```
Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation(); 
Bitmap bitmap = instrumentation.getUiAutomation().takeScreenshot();
```

For this to work the test needs to be run on a computer with the device connected via usb.

Alternatively you could try using the [UIAutomator python wrapper,](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator#screen-actions-of-the-device) which does the heavy lifting for you, but you still need the device connected via usb (or wifi, if adb over wifi is supported).